# Python PyTorch Error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch.utils.tensorboard'

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, tensorboard

I'm coding in Python on a Jupyter Notebook (Python 3) on Windows, and I've installed PyTorch and TensorBoard. My problem is that i'm getting this error message:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch.utils.tensorboard'`

I've already tried to use `pip install future` but the error remains, how can I fix this?

Here's how I'm importing `torch.utils.tensorboard`

```
from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `pip install tensorboard or pip3 install tensorboard`
OR 
`pip install --upgrade tensorboard && pip install --upgrade torch`

Comment: Hello, this didn't work. I get the `Requirements already up-to-date` message from the console. Is there any other way?
Note: The `pip install tensorboard` got the same message, but with the `pip3 install tensorboard` the console says it doesn't recognize this command.

Comment: Are you using python2 or python3

Comment: I'm using Python 3

Comment: Install ```sudo apt-get -y install python3-pip``` then ```pip3 install tensorboard```

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to mension but I'm using Windows.

Comment: I uninstalled the PyTorch and then installed it back, now i don't get tis error anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reinstall with the torch version below:

```
pip3 install torch==1.4.0
```

Answer (score -2):

Guess you are running on a machine w/o GPU device.
usually you need pytorch with GPU version to achieve tensorboard import in torch.utils